# Can we get [behind] the burnination of this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

### This is a discussion, not an invitation to burninate this tag

The [behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/behind) tag [has 53 questions at the time of me posting this](https://web.archive.org/web/20230314050634/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/behind), so we need to follow the formal burnination process (And no, don't go and remove this tag from four questions to get it below the limit - this has been attempted before on tags slightly above the threshold and may earn anyone attempting that a suspension unless a mod explicitly says otherwise).

Onto the burnination criteria!

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?

This tag is super ambiguous. I suppose it refers to *something* behind *something else*, but that gives almost no information at all.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Maybe? This tag is really far too vague to answer this question properly

> Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

Nope. None at all.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Certainly not.

---

Given this, I propose that this tag is burninated.

Thoughts? Agree? Disagree?

Comment: Typo: "*to**o** vague*". // The Tag *does* add meaningful info for some Posts, I find... // You could come under the 50 Threads as some are about "Code Behind" but only tagged with `behind` while there is a `code-behind` Tag. // Maybe a `css-front-behind` Tag could be created to catch all Posts about CSS...? // Tags with `*ahead` in them are "*a mess*" also...

Comment: @chivracq I've fixed the typo, thanks for catching it. Would you mind posting your suggestion for about what to do as an answer, though? Thanks!

Comment: Boah..., my Comment is just meant as a Comment/mini-Feedback, I only had a quick look... I expected actually to find many Posts about "Lookbehind", but nope, the `lookbehind` Tag does "its job" neatly... (... which is not the case with `lookahead` + `regex-look-ahead`, oops...).

Comment: Some Remark: "*This is a discussion, not an invitation to burninate this tag*" <> "*Given this, I propose that this tag is burninated.*" Those 2 sentences are quite contradictory, in a same Post, I would think...! (+ Title also: "*Can we get [behind] the burnination of this tag?*" => 2+1)

Comment: It's a *proposal putting the topic up for discussion*, not an invitation to get started *actually doing it*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes, get rid of it; this tag is too ambiguous to be useful**

The questions seem to be generally about:

- Displaying one thing behind another, or something displaying behind something when it shouldn't.  Most of these should probably be tagged [z-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/z-order) instead.
- .NET code-behind.  These should be tagged [code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-behind) instead.
- An application that is behind a [proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proxy), [router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/router), [nat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nat), [firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firewall), etc.  Those should just use the relevant tag instead.

I think the tag should be removed entirely and replaced with the appropriate tags from the list above.

Comment: Friendly reminder to folks that it still isn't time to actually burninate it yet, and we still need to follow [the official process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).